# Isotope Items outside of container on filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, imagesloaded

I am using Isotope with Wordpress, and struggling with a particular bug, which i have tried all the options on here and other sources, but to no avail.

I have basically the items flying outside the container when I use the filter. Please see my code below. I am using this with Bootstrap.

```html
<div class="profiles__filter__wrap__option">
  <div class="option__reset" data-filter="*">X</div>
  <div class="option__select" data-filter=".female-physiques">Women</div>
</div>
<div class="profiles__filter__wrap__option">
  <div class="option__reset" data-filter="*">X</div>
  <div class="option__select" data-filter=".male-physiques">Men</div>
</div>
<div class="profiles__filter__wrap__option">
  <div class="option__reset" data-filter="*">X</div>
  <div class="option__select" data-filter=".ad">Ads</div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $container = $('.profiles__wrap');

  $container.isotope({
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    itemSelector: '.profiles__wrap__profile',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: '.profiles__wrap__profile',
      horizontalOrder: true,
    }
  });

  $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $container.isotope('layout');
  });
});
```